# How to request mobile website in cordova in appbrowser?

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, inappbrowser

I have two website:

```
1) www.demo.com for desktop
2) www.m.demo.com for mobile
```

I want to open www.m.demo.com in inappbrowser of cordova with url of www.demo.com.

Comment: not enough info, how do you decide which one to load when you try on a browser?

Comment: My website www.demo.com. will decide based on request from inappbrowser which website should be loaded in response.

Comment: You will definitely need to have the server determine if the user is from Cordova's inappbrowser. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16308626/541591

Comment: Thanks james, above link is helpful for me.

Comment: yeah, but my point is HOW do you decide which page to show? show us your code

Comment: According to me it is done by url parameter.